# Post title in search results is truncated at an inadequate length

Tags: bug, search, elasticsearch

What is the reason to truncate the post title in the [search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=How%20many%20questions%20on%20meta%20have%20asked)?

> [image: ...]

Seems there is a bug in width calculation to fit title into single line. But this is just my speculation.

Title display is currently being truncated at 92 characters while they are normally allowed to be 150 chars long.