# Could the tag names be fully written out in the list of awarded tag badges?

Tags: bug, tags, badges

On English Language and Usage, [20 people](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) have been awarded the "[single-word-r...]" gold tag badge. Except that's not it's real name; it's actually for [single-word-r**equests**]:

[image]

13 characters isn't a lot, especially not now that tags can be up to [35 characters long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/323179). Can the full tag name be displayed here?

Comment: There are many issues related to the length of user-defined content. A couple from my own list: [tag search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316251/339911) and [title truncation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306699/339911). I saw much more in UI due to my participation in translation UI to Russian, since site design isn't flexible enough.